# Salvar arquivos com o mesmo nome

Tags: c#

A aplicação salva fotos de umas peças aqui no serviço, e usamos um leitor de código de barras que funciona como teclado, para ler e salvar os dados automaticamente, sem que o operador precise usar o mouse, porém quando duas fotos tem que ser tiradas do mesma peça, gera esse transtorno pro operador, onde ele tem que renomar o arquivo na hora do overwrite para não sobreescrever.

É possível salvar arquivos com o mesmo nome em C#, como posso fazer para evitar o conflito? Ou fazer os arquivos renomearem automaticamente, sem precisar o usuário ter que fazer manualmente.

**Tentei ultilizar esse cógido:**

```
if (!Directory.Exists(""))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\text");
}

string FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"c:\text", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss"));
File.Create(FileName + ".txt");
```

**Porém não obtive sucesso, meu código para salvar imagens é esse aqui:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //abre a opção de salvar como, para selecionar a pasta
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog
        {
            //InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonPictures),
            Filter = "JPeg Image|*.jpg|Bitmap Image|*.bmp|Gif Image|*.gif",
            Title = "Salvar o arquivo de imagem",
            RestoreDirectory = true

        };
        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(""))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\text");
            }

            string FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"c:\text", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss"));
            File.Create(FileName + ".txt");

        }

        // se o nome do arquivo não for vazio, abre para salvar
        if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
        {
            // salva a imagem por fileStream
            System.IO.FileStream fs =
            (System.IO.FileStream)saveFileDialog1.OpenFile();
            // Salva a imagem no formato certo
            switch (saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    this.pictureBoxScreenshot.Image.Save(fs,
                       System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    this.pictureBoxScreenshot.Image.Save(fs,
                       System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    this.pictureBoxScreenshot.Image.Save(fs,
                       System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                    break;
            }

            fs.Close();
        }
    } //...
}
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, você não pode salvar arquivos com o mesmo nome e extensão, no mesmo diretório...

Comment: Na realidade o que esse comando faz é colocar um comentario com um horario diferente da primeira que foi salva, por isso ele salva ambos arquivos ou mais com o mesmo nome, porém não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar

Comment: Não precisa ser nem o mesmo nome, apenas se na hora que fosse usar a aplicação para salvar, não aparecesse para renomear, fizesse isso automaticamente, tipo exemplo - exemplo[1] - exemplo[2] , já me ajudaria

Comment: Nesse caso a prática mais comum é você concatenar a data o final do nome do arquivo, Exemplo teste_20180409100836.txt

Comment: Outra coisa que você pode fazer é renomear o arquivo antigo adicionando a sua data de alteração no nome e deixar o atual sempre com o nome fixo

Comment: então é que no caso a aplicação ela salva fotos de umas peças aqui no serviço, dai ele usa um leitor de código de barras que funciona como teclado, fazendo esse salvamento se tornar automatico, sem ele precisar ficar usando o mouse, porém quando duas fotos tem que ser tiradas do mesma peça, gera esse transtorno pro operador, onde ele tem que renomar o arquivo na hora do overwrite e usar o mouse pra terminar de salvar, por isso queria automatizar isso

Comment: Seria só corrigir o erro conceitual de usar a leitura como nome do arquivo, ou simplesmente adicionar um sufixo incremental.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para quem um dia tiver o mesmo problema que o meu, consegui solucionar o caso assim:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //abre a opção de salvar como, para selecionar a pasta

        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog

        {
            //InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonPictures),

            Filter = "JPeg Image|*.jpg|Bitmap Image|*.bmp|Gif Image|*.gif",
            Title = "Salvar o arquivo de imagem",
            RestoreDirectory = true,
         };

        saveFileDialog1.OverwritePrompt = false;
        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();


        // se o nome do arquivo não for vazio, abre para salvar
        if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
        {
            int fileCount = 0;
            string fullPath = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
            string fileNamewithoutExt = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullPath);
            string dirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(fullPath);
            string newPath = string.Empty;

            while (File.Exists(newPath = Path.Combine(dirPath, fileNamewithoutExt + (fileCount > 0 ? "[" + fileCount + "]" : "") + ext)))
            { fileCount++; }

            // Salva a imagem no formato certo
            switch (saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    this.pictureBoxScreenshot.Image.Save(newPath,
                       System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    this.pictureBoxScreenshot.Image.Save(newPath,
                       System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    this.pictureBoxScreenshot.Image.Save(newPath,
                       System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                    break;
            }

        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Erro " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```